# SQL Server 2005 database comparison

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I am working on a project of Data Centralization. I have to transfer data from two databases into a third newly created master database.The existing databases hold the same type of data, the tables are the same etc. But before that, I need to check whether the master tables from the existing two databases are the same i.e. the column names, number etc are same of the two same tables in both the databases. 
For e.g. Both the databases have a table called SROMaster. I need to check if SROMaster from db1 will hold the same columns as SROMaster from db2. Can someone help me? Thanks!

Comment: From what platform/language do you want to do this check? T-SQL? C#? Something else? Can you connect to both databases from that platform you're running your comparison on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what platform/language you're using - but in any case, to test if a given table exists, you can use this T-SQL to do the job:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM sys.tables t
WHERE t.Name = 'SROMaster'
```

That will return a row with all the info about the table - if it exists - otherwise you can nothing back.

Once you have the table, you can check what columns the table has by using:

```
SELECT c.*
FROM sys.columns c
INNER JOIN sys.tables t ON c.object_id = t.object_id
WHERE t.Name = 'SROMaster'
ORDER BY c.column_id
```

You'll get back a data set of rows with information about the columns - compare those two lists you're getting to see if you have the same columns in both table's `SROMaster` table.

Answer (score 0):

To check a single table, you could just issue the convert table to Create script command on both databases and compare the results by hand.

You may also have to use some judgment re: what is compatible, i.e., are the columns in the same order? Does that matter to you based on how you plan on converted it.

If you have a large number of table to compare, you don't want to do this by hand. There are tools for this, or you can roll you own by having proc that run through the system catalog.

Given that you are asking this question, I suspect you are better off looking for an existing tool to do the heavy lifting of table comparison. This is not considered a stack overflow question though.